# Google sheet: Can an option be remove on the dropdown menu (data validation)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I'm using the data validation for my dropdown list. The criteria is "List from a Range".

Here's my column:

```
MALE
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3

FEMALE
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
```

Male and female are visible in the dropdown menu. Is there a way for me to remove it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your ranges from

```
MALE
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3

FEMALE
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
```

to your new ranges

```
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3

Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
```

So if your range is `A1:A4`, change it to `A2:A4`

Comment: How can I put this using the data validation? It doesn't accept two range values.

Answer (score 1):

As @marikamitsos points out you are including the cells with values "MALE" and "FEMALE" in the ranges you are selecting as cells to be shown in your drop-down list.

The cells you include in the range selected will **all** appear in the drop-down, as stated in the [support-article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103). So removing the top cells from your chosen ranges will do the trick.

Comment: Is there no other way for me to remove it on the dropdown without removing it there?

Comment: No, but you can change the range in the data validation from list without removing the words from the cells, just selece the range below the word that you don't want to show.

Answer (score 0):

What I do with this is that I just create a new column and refer it to the cells with names and then removed the MALE and FEMALE on it, then hide the new column and use it for the data validation.